# Ansible: How to differentiate the hosts between two host-groups

Tags: ansible

My hosts file is like

```
[app]
192.168.6.100
192.168.6.101

[DB]
192.168.7.200
192.168.7.201
```

And I want to run two different **.yml** files separately for each of these hosts using `- include app.yml` and `- include db.yml` from a `main.yml` file

To differentiate between the hosts I used `when: "{{ groups['app'] }}"` and `when: "{{ groups['db'] }}"`, but its not working properly. I'm also not sure whether its a right approach or not

```
# cat main.yml 
---
 - include: app.yml
   when: "{{ groups['app'] }}"
 - include: db.yml 
   when: "{{ groups['db'] }}"
```

Comment: Use roles. Also I recommend reading http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_roles.html To tell Ansible which hosts to run playbook on you just use `hosts: app` or `hosts: DB` directive in the beginning of playbook. Tasks/includes/roles go under `hosts`

Comment: Did you try `when: inventory_hostname in groups.apps`?

Comment: ya, i'm using roles. This is the part of creating two different set of users for two different servers. Its working good now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The correct syntax would be:

```
---
 - include: app.yml
   when: "'app' in group_names"
 - include: db.yml 
   when: "'db' in group_names"
```